# Python class attribute error despite existing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I found a solution for this on here, but then I realized it was Python 2.7. I'm using Python 3.3.7, and I've recently been experimenting with classes, and I believe I may have ended up confusing myself. I have two files; my class file (Dice.py):

```
class Dice:
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides

    @classmethod
    def roll(self):
        return self.sides + 2
```

and my main file.

```
from Dice import Dice

Dice(int(input('How many sides are on the dice? ')))
print(Dice.roll())
```

Very simple for now, theoretically. However, I've been running into a strange attribute error that's had me stuck on these ten or so lines of codes for far longer than I'd care to admit. I keep receiving a "AttributeError: type object 'Dice' has no attribute 'sides'
" each time I attempt to run the main file, which should theoretically give me an answer of the input amount + 2.

I've gone through and initialized it multiple ways, added @classmethod, renamed the attribute and all of that; I just can't same to shake this error. I was wondering exactly what the error meant if it wasn't referring to the init function at the start, and how I could fix it so it can actually run. Thank you!

Comment: Classmethods don't work that way.   Are you certain you want ```roll()``` as a classmethod?

Comment: Why are you using `@classmethod`?

Comment: @wim
Honestly I'm not quite sure, I was perusing here and I think I saw another solution used that to solve and implemented obviously unsuccessfully. Without it I receive another error I just couldn't figure out either; Dice.roll() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' . I'm not sure how I'm supposed to include self other than it being... self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more idiomatic method to write a class method is

```
class Dice:
    ...

    @classmethod
    def roll(cls):
        ...
```

Note the parameter is usually called `cls`, not `self`. What the `@classmethod` method does, is make it so that when you call `Dice.roll()`, the 'instance' that's passed to the method is the object `Dice` - literally, the class that owns the method (not any particular instance of the class). This is usually used in conjunction with inheritance and polymorphism.

Now, since `__init__()` has never been called on the `Dice` class itself (it would only ever be called on an *instance* of the `Dice` class), the `Dice` class does not ever have an attribute called `sides` attached to it.

---

In your case, you probably want `roll()` to be an instance method, and to save the new instance to a variable:

```
class Dice:
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides

    def roll(self):
        return self.sides + 2

die = Dice(int(input('How many sides are on the dice? ')))
print(die.roll())

# alternatively

sides = int(input('How many sides are on the dice? '))
print(Dice(sides).roll())
```